# Remove duplicates in a Pandas data frame based on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data-set and I want to remove duplicates based on the bool column.

| datetime | number | bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-14 10:15:00 | 195.35 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-14 11:15:00 | 195.8 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-14 12:15:00 | 195.87 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-14 13:15:00 | 196.06 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-14 14:15:00 | 195.97 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-14 15:15:00 | 195.98 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-15 09:15:00 | 196.23 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-15 10:15:00 | 196.3 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-15 11:15:00 | 196.26 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-15 12:15:00 | 196.4 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-15 13:15:00 | 196.28 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-15 14:15:00 | 197.14 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-15 15:15:00 | 197.08 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-16 09:15:00 | 197.85 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-16 10:15:00 | 198.01 | TRUE |

Resulting data should look like this

| datetime | number | bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-14 10:15:00 | 195.35 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-14 14:15:00 | 195.97 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-15 09:15:00 | 196.23 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-15 11:15:00 | 196.26 | TRUE |
| 2023-02-15 14:15:00 | 197.14 | FALSE |
| 2023-02-16 09:15:00 | 197.85 | TRUE |

I tried pandas drop_duplicates but this will group the whole bool column and then removes duplicates, that will result in only 2 rows.

PS: I might just loop through all rows and compare to the previous but I am looking for some Panda's native way of doing this, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare shifted values by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
out = df[df['bool'].ne(df['bool'].shift())]
print (out)
               datetime  number   bool
0   2023-02-14 10:15:00  195.35  False
4   2023-02-14 14:15:00  195.97   True
6   2023-02-15 09:15:00  196.23  False
8   2023-02-15 11:15:00  196.26   True
11  2023-02-15 14:15:00  197.14  False
13  2023-02-16 09:15:00  197.85   True
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```
without_duplicates = df.duplicated(['datetime', 'number'], keep='last') & df['bool']
print(df[~without_duplicates])
```

Sample that I tried:

[image]

Comment: answer is wrong, do you test it with data from question?

Comment: @jezrael no i couldn't reuse the OPs data , but used a test data

Comment: there is problem copy data from question?